Chip identification, SOP-4, "HPTD"
Anyone know what this chip is? The dimensions are approx 4mm by 2.5mm. Also I believe one of the pins is connected to Vout of a voltage regulator. Could it be a voltage detector?


Looks like an optoisolator. Where exactly this is, what's around it, is it a power supply with this chip between mains and low volage side?

It's an Isocom Components ISP281D optocoupler.


(Source: lcsc.com)
